# redux-saga unit test fails unexpectedly

Tags: unit-testing, redux-saga

We have a function like this:

```
export function* postPermitApplicationRequest() {
  try {
    const uris = yield select(state => getUris(state));

    .... (more yields hereafter)
```

We test this function with Jest and Chai as follows:

```
...
const action = { type: Action.POST_PERMIT_APPLICATION };
const generator = postPermitApplicationRequest(action);    

it('must select uris from state', () => {
  const nextCall = generator.next().value;
  const uris = select(state => getUris(state));
  expect(nextCall).to.deep.equal(uris);
});
```

However the expect fails:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, SELECT) } to deeply equal { Object (@@redux-saga/IO, SELECT) }

  at Assertion.assertEqual (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/core/assertions.js:485:19)
  at Assertion.ctx.(anonymous function) [as equal] (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/utils/addMethod.js:41:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/pa/PermitApplicationServiceSagas.test.js:20:43)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

The two objects both look like:

```
{ '@@redux-saga/IO': true,
  SELECT: { selector: [Function], args: [] } }
```

However the selector functions are different. The one that is the outcome of generator.next() contains code coverage skip hints:

```
function (state) {/* istanbul ignore next */cov_zrpq42gyn.f[12]++;cov_zrpq42gyn.s[19]++;return (/* istanbul ignore next */(0, _Selectors.getUris)(state));}
```

while the original function doesn't:

```
function (state) {return (0, _Selectors.getUris)(state);}
```

It looks like generator.next() adds these hints and the assertion fails

What do we wrong here?

We use redux-saga 0.14.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tests fail because in your saga and your test you create a new functions every time you execute the code. These both functions will be compared but are not the same instance.

You can simply use `select(getUris)` in your saga and your test because both will reference to the same function.

Your saga:

```
export function* postPermitApplicationRequest() {
  try {
    const uris = yield select(getUris);

    .... (more yields hereafter)
```

Your test:

```
...
const action = { type: Action.POST_PERMIT_APPLICATION };
const generator = postPermitApplicationRequest(action);    

it('must select uris from state', () => {
  const nextCall = generator.next().value;
  const uris = select(getUris);
  expect(nextCall).to.deep.equal(uris);
});
```